# How to link lex.yy.c with main.c by makefile?

Tags: c

In main.c, I call getToken function, which is contained in lex.yy.c generated by flex. I want to compile them by using makefile

```
CC = gcc
TARGET = lexic

OBJS = util.o main.o

$(TARGET) : lex.yy.c util.o main.o
        $(CC) lex.yy.c -ll util.o main.o
util.o : globals.h util.h util.c
        $(CC) -c -o util.o util.c
main.o : globals.h util.h main.c
        $(CC) -o main.o main.c
```

I made like this, but the compiler couldn't find where getToken function is.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't include your header files in your call to the compiler. Also, use the `-c` flag when compiling `main.c` to obtain an object.

Comment: Take a closer look at how you build the `main.o` file. Are you sure you pass all the correct flags to build an object file? I recommend you learn about *implicit rules* which will cause `make` to build object files with the correct flags automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't build an object file named `main.o`, your rule attempt to build an *executable* by that name.

The simple and most immediate way to solve your problem is to add the `-c` flag when building:

```
main.o : globals.h util.h main.c
    $(CC) -c -o main.o main.c
#         ^^
# Note flag added
```

---

A "better" and at least simpler way is to rely on the [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) that `make` have for creating, among other things, object and executable files.

Then you could simply have your `Makefile` look something like this:

```
# CFLAGS is the C compiler flags
# Add flags to enable verbose warnings (always a good idea)
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

TARGET = lexic

# The libraries to link the target application with
LDLIBS = -ll

# By default the make program uses the first target
default: $(TARGET)

# Because of the implicit rules, make will be able to link the executable by itself
$(TARGET): lex.yy.o util.o main.o

# Also because of implicit rules, object files will be created automatically as well
# But we list them here to specify their header-file dependencies
util.o main.o: globals.h util.h
```

Important note: The implicit rule for Lex files (including Flex) is to create the source file `X.c` from the file `X.l`. So unless your Lex file is names `lex.yy.l` then you need to change the name of the object file `lex.yy.o` in the above `Makefile`.